# No chart is shown using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have started using HighCharts and I have come up with the below code to test it out but the problem is that no chart is shown.

I want a simple line chart with dates running along the bottom and numbers running upwards.

### Code

```
<?php

$sql = array(
    'user'     => 'removed',
    'password' => 'removed',
    'server'   => 'removed',
    'db'       => 'removed'
);

$conn = oci_connect($sql['user'], $sql['password'], $sql['server'].'/'.$sql['db']);

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error( htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR );
}

$result = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT EntryDate, COUNT(OrderNo) FROM Orders GROUP BY EntryDate");
oci_execute($result);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result)) {
   $data0[] = $row['0'];
   $data1[] = $row['1'];
}
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         type: 'line'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: [<?php echo join($data0, ',') ?>]
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Orders'
          }
      },
      series: [{
         data: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
         pointStart: 0,
         pointInterval
      }]
});
</script>

<div id="container" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
```

### Results

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         type: 'line'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: [01-NOV-12,02-NOV-12,03-NOV-12,05-NOV-12,06-NOV-12,07-NOV-12,08-NOV-12,09-NOV-12,12-NOV-12,13-NOV-12,14-NOV-12,15-NOV-12,16-NOV-12,19-NOV-12,20-NOV-12,21-NOV-12,22-NOV-12,23-NOV-12,24-NOV-12,26-NOV-12,27-NOV-12,28-NOV-12,29-NOV-12,30-NOV-12,01-DEC-12,02-DEC-12,03-DEC-12,04-DEC-12,05-DEC-12,06-DEC-12,07-DEC-12,10-DEC-12,11-DEC-12,12-DEC-12,13-DEC-12,14-DEC-12,17-DEC-12,18-DEC-12,19-DEC-12,20-DEC-12,21-DEC-12,03-JAN-13,04-JAN-13,05-JAN-13,07-JAN-13,08-JAN-13,09-JAN-13,10-JAN-13,11-JAN-13,14-JAN-13,15-JAN-13,16-JAN-13,17-JAN-13,18-JAN-13,21-JAN-13,22-JAN-13,23-JAN-13,24-JAN-13,25-JAN-13,28-JAN-13,29-JAN-13,30-JAN-13,31-JAN-13,01-FEB-13,04-FEB-13,05-FEB-13,06-FEB-13,07-FEB-13,08-FEB-13,11-FEB-13,12-FEB-13,13-FEB-13,14-FEB-13,15-FEB-13,16-FEB-13,18-FEB-13,19-FEB-13,20-FEB-13,21-FEB-13,22-FEB-13,25-FEB-13,26-FEB-13,27-FEB-13,28-FEB-13,01-MAR-13,02-MAR-13,04-MAR-13,05-MAR-13,06-MAR-13,07-MAR-13,08-MAR-13,11-MAR-13,12-MAR-13,13-MAR-13,14-MAR-13,15-MAR-13,16-MAR-13,17-MAR-13,18-MAR-13,19-MAR-13,20-MAR-13,21-MAR-13,22-MAR-13,25-MAR-13,26-MAR-13,27-MAR-13,28-MAR-13,02-APR-13,03-APR-13,04-APR-13,05-APR-13,08-APR-13,09-APR-13,10-APR-13,11-APR-13,12-APR-13,15-APR-13,16-APR-13,17-APR-13,18-APR-13,19-APR-13,22-APR-13,23-APR-13,24-APR-13,25-APR-13,26-APR-13,29-APR-13,30-APR-13,01-MAY-13,02-MAY-13,03-MAY-13,07-MAY-13,08-MAY-13,09-MAY-13,10-MAY-13,13-MAY-13,14-MAY-13,15-MAY-13,16-MAY-13,17-MAY-13,18-MAY-13,20-MAY-13,21-MAY-13,22-MAY-13,23-MAY-13,24-MAY-13,25-MAY-13,28-MAY-13,29-MAY-13,30-MAY-13,31-MAY-13,03-JUN-13,04-JUN-13,05-JUN-13,06-JUN-13,07-JUN-13,10-JUN-13,11-JUN-13,12-JUN-13,13-JUN-13,14-JUN-13,17-JUN-13,18-JUN-13,19-JUN-13,20-JUN-13,21-JUN-13,24-JUN-13,25-JUN-13,26-JUN-13,27-JUN-13,28-JUN-13,01-JUL-13,02-JUL-13,03-JUL-13,04-JUL-13,05-JUL-13,08-JUL-13,09-JUL-13,10-JUL-13,11-JUL-13,12-JUL-13,15-JUL-13,16-JUL-13,17-JUL-13,18-JUL-13,19-JUL-13,22-JUL-13,23-JUL-13,24-JUL-13,25-JUL-13,26-JUL-13,29-JUL-13,30-JUL-13,31-JUL-13,01-AUG-13,02-AUG-13,05-AUG-13,06-AUG-13,07-AUG-13,08-AUG-13,09-AUG-13,12-AUG-13,13-AUG-13,14-AUG-13,15-AUG-13,16-AUG-13,19-AUG-13,20-AUG-13,21-AUG-13,22-AUG-13,23-AUG-13,27-AUG-13,28-AUG-13,29-AUG-13,30-AUG-13,02-SEP-13,03-SEP-13,04-SEP-13,05-SEP-13,06-SEP-13,09-SEP-13,10-SEP-13,11-SEP-13,12-SEP-13,13-SEP-13,15-SEP-13,16-SEP-13,17-SEP-13,18-SEP-13,19-SEP-13,20-SEP-13,21-SEP-13,23-SEP-13,24-SEP-13,25-SEP-13,26-SEP-13,27-SEP-13,28-SEP-13,30-SEP-13,01-OCT-13,02-OCT-13,03-OCT-13,04-OCT-13,05-OCT-13,07-OCT-13,08-OCT-13,09-OCT-13,10-OCT-13,11-OCT-13,12-OCT-13,14-OCT-13,15-OCT-13,16-OCT-13,17-OCT-13,18-OCT-13,21-OCT-13,22-OCT-13,23-OCT-13,24-OCT-13,25-OCT-13,28-OCT-13,29-OCT-13,30-OCT-13,31-OCT-13,01-NOV-13,04-NOV-13,05-NOV-13,06-NOV-13,07-NOV-13,08-NOV-13,11-NOV-13,12-NOV-13,13-NOV-13,14-NOV-13,15-NOV-13,18-NOV-13,19-NOV-13,20-NOV-13,21-NOV-13,22-NOV-13,25-NOV-13,26-NOV-13,27-NOV-13,28-NOV-13,29-NOV-13,02-DEC-13,03-DEC-13,04-DEC-13,05-DEC-13,06-DEC-13,09-DEC-13,10-DEC-13,11-DEC-13,12-DEC-13,13-DEC-13,16-DEC-13,17-DEC-13,18-DEC-13,19-DEC-13,20-DEC-13,02-JAN-14,03-JAN-14,06-JAN-14,07-JAN-14,08-JAN-14,09-JAN-14,10-JAN-14,13-JAN-14,14-JAN-14,15-JAN-14,16-JAN-14,17-JAN-14,20-JAN-14,21-JAN-14,22-JAN-14,23-JAN-14,24-JAN-14,27-JAN-14,28-JAN-14,29-JAN-14,30-JAN-14,31-JAN-14,03-FEB-14,04-FEB-14,05-FEB-14,06-FEB-14,07-FEB-14,10-FEB-14,11-FEB-14,12-FEB-14,13-FEB-14,14-FEB-14,17-FEB-14,18-FEB-14,19-FEB-14,20-FEB-14,21-FEB-14,24-FEB-14,25-FEB-14,26-FEB-14,27-FEB-14,28-FEB-14,03-MAR-14,04-MAR-14,05-MAR-14,06-MAR-14,07-MAR-14,10-MAR-14,11-MAR-14,12-MAR-14,13-MAR-14,14-MAR-14,17-MAR-14,18-MAR-14,19-MAR-14,20-MAR-14,21-MAR-14,24-MAR-14,25-MAR-14,26-MAR-14,27-MAR-14,28-MAR-14,31-MAR-14,01-APR-14,02-APR-14,03-APR-14,04-APR-14,07-APR-14,08-APR-14,09-APR-14,10-APR-14,11-APR-14,14-APR-14,15-APR-14,16-APR-14,17-APR-14,22-APR-14,23-APR-14,24-APR-14,25-APR-14,28-APR-14,29-APR-14,30-APR-14,01-MAY-14,02-MAY-14,06-MAY-14,07-MAY-14,08-MAY-14,09-MAY-14,12-MAY-14,13-MAY-14,14-MAY-14,15-MAY-14,16-MAY-14,19-MAY-14,20-MAY-14,21-MAY-14,22-MAY-14,23-MAY-14,27-MAY-14,28-MAY-14,29-MAY-14,30-MAY-14,02-JUN-14,03-JUN-14,04-JUN-14,05-JUN-14,06-JUN-14,09-JUN-14,10-JUN-14,11-JUN-14,12-JUN-14,13-JUN-14,16-JUN-14,17-JUN-14,18-JUN-14,19-JUN-14,20-JUN-14,23-JUN-14,24-JUN-14,25-JUN-14,26-JUN-14,27-JUN-14,30-JUN-14,01-JUL-14,02-JUL-14,03-JUL-14,04-JUL-14,07-JUL-14,08-JUL-14,09-JUL-14,10-JUL-14,11-JUL-14,14-JUL-14,15-JUL-14,16-JUL-14,17-JUL-14,18-JUL-14,21-JUL-14,22-JUL-14,23-JUL-14,24-JUL-14,25-JUL-14,28-JUL-14,29-JUL-14,30-JUL-14,31-JUL-14,01-AUG-14,04-AUG-14,05-AUG-14,06-AUG-14,07-AUG-14,08-AUG-14,11-AUG-14,12-AUG-14,13-AUG-14,14-AUG-14,15-AUG-14,18-AUG-14,19-AUG-14,20-AUG-14,21-AUG-14,22-AUG-14,26-AUG-14,27-AUG-14,28-AUG-14,29-AUG-14,01-SEP-14,02-SEP-14,03-SEP-14,04-SEP-14,05-SEP-14]
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Orders'
          }
      },
      series: [{
         data: [543,555,91,488,626,498,639,516,553,687,616,887,514,483,643,443,699,436,131,389,721,475,878,431,409,19,513,841,631,636,286,701,746,574,597,404,561,772,450,367,122,380,552,111,383,460,640,573,423,469,758,680,550,206,350,464,363,702,595,467,646,589,713,409,499,672,682,670,506,581,495,866,602,566,211,477,605,568,809,647,577,791,517,808,319,201,515,831,611,653,431,453,737,510,573,621,163,65,810,870,631,774,648,639,714,697,589,543,395,738,548,883,670,745,629,553,572,676,806,860,605,686,766,693,712,594,657,579,927,867,657,723,643,826,552,824,730,726,910,485,200,715,799,697,879,579,178,705,865,766,532,734,776,700,764,688,781,643,725,818,560,616,865,828,730,548,698,533,796,850,581,590,569,904,746,376,603,940,548,893,486,713,708,744,978,675,642,737,759,632,715,446,992,756,863,507,532,744,812,538,709,577,815,590,831,575,620,768,618,878,621,806,776,814,555,524,958,752,853,774,613,923,720,888,671,6,483,626,639,755,681,325,547,759,788,520,617,458,611,1021,878,909,653,139,515,794,750,708,555,155,549,744,755,997,531,534,801,702,824,550,574,773,829,705,475,603,688,881,805,645,634,873,644,748,619,655,791,655,800,632,585,814,646,743,693,564,823,699,848,539,580,726,587,722,504,562,557,408,443,285,517,299,483,536,610,731,509,554,667,651,570,544,570,650,688,503,598,699,655,676,612,566,632,730,706,707,569,591,885,728,780,504,648,691,840,664,648,746,760,651,629,499,674,843,582,764,745,767,724,661,831,584,788,954,716,690,581,719,926,807,749,454,681,945,798,856,686,603,905,711,845,470,604,845,753,615,767,713,852,546,819,864,831,746,600,862,733,907,717,770,868,789,997,605,886,808,763,652,721,633,698,760,713,681,898,821,819,721,787,738,767,728,540,660,759,767,620,615,687,852,751,727,527,680,733,735,750,623,862,811,845,805,720,772,811,861,755,648,773,799,884,801,652,605,700,884,896,714,877,808,810,669,774,784,766,989,794,741,810,870,818,576,629,676,744,733,679,750,880,878,604,450],
         pointStart: 0,
         pointInterval
      }]
});
</script>

<div id="container" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
```

Please can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues. First one is `categories` should be a list of strings, as other people already have mentioned:

```
categories: ["<?php echo join($data0, '","') ?>"]
```

Second issue: `new Highcharts.Chart()` is called before #container exists in the DOM. So you have to wrap the whole JS in a function to call it **after** DOM has loaded. This little jQuery piece will call the Highcharts function after the DOM has loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 // your JS-code
});
</script>
```

Btw, both of these errors are logged in the JS console (don't know which browser you're using and thus how to access it).

Answer (score 1):

The categories should be an array of strings

```
categories: ["<?php echo join('","',$data0) ?>"]
```

Comment: What do you mean? That's exactly what I have `categories: [<?php echo join($data0, ',') ?>]`.

Comment: @user3973427 Notice the quotations that wrap the embedded PHP statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your categories must be strings - currently their output as simple characters after eachother.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         type: 'line'
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: ['01-NOV-12', '02-NOV-12']
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Orders'
          }
      },
      series: [{
         data: [543,555]
      }]
});
```

You can achieve this by changing your `categories: [<?php echo join($data0, ',') ?>]` to the following:

```
categories: [<?php echo "'".implode($data0, "','")."'" ?>]
```

The `implode(seperator, array)` function will put all of the values in your array right after each other, seperated by the given characters - expanding that to begin and end with an apostrophe will result in your dates being output as string category names.

Also you've got a `pointInterval` attribute there at the end of your JS without any value, that was also resulting in the failure of the code.
I've deprecated some of your sample data, but you'll get the point.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code isn't executed on `document ready` event. Thus perhaps the div with id='container' hasn't been created yet and the chart has nowhere to be drawn. Try putting the code after the div like that:

```
<div id='container'>
</div>
<script>
//highcharts config code
</script>
```

You could also put the javascript in a anonymous function and execute it after the declaration:

```
<div id='container'>
</div>
<script>
(function(){
  //Highcharts config code here.
} ());
</script>
```

Also as the other answers are pointing out, the config is in json format so you should use valid JSON values e.g. `string, number, true or false, or null.`

Answer (score 0):

Try change this line

```
categories: ["<?php echo implode('","',$data0) ?>"]
```